# Parallel.For SendAsync to BufferBlock to Async Transform?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, parallel.for

I am learning about the `TPL Dataflow` Library. So far it's exactly what I was looking for.

I've created a simple class (below) that performs the following functions

- Upon execution of `ImportPropertiesForBranch` I go to a 3rd party api and get a list of properties
- A xml list is returned and deserialized into an array of property data (id, api endpoint, lastupdated). There are around 400+ properties (as in houses).
- I then use a `Parallel.For` to `SendAsync` the property data into my `propertyBufferBlock`
- The `propertyBufferBlock` is linked to a `propertyXmlBlock` (which itself is a `TransformBlock`).
- The `propertyXmlBlock` then (asynchronously) goes back to the API (using the api endpoint supplied in the property data) and fetches the property xml for deserialization.
- Once the xml is returned and becomes available, we can then deserialize
- Later, I'll add more `TransformBlock`s to persist it to a data store.

So my questions are;

- Are there any potential bottlenecks or areas of the code that could be troublesome? I'm aware that I've not included any error handling or cancellation (this is to come).
- Is it ok to `await` async calls inside a `TransformBlock` or is this a
  bottleneck?
- Although the code works , I am worried about the buffering and asyncronsity of the `Parallel.For`, `BufferBlock` and async in the `TransformBlock`. I'm not sure its the best way and I maybe mixing up some concepts.

Any guidance, improvemets and pitfall advice welcomed.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using My.Interfaces;
using My.XmlService.Models;

namespace My.ImportService
{
    public class ImportService
    {

        private readonly IApiService _apiService;
        private readonly IXmlService _xmlService;
        private readonly IRepositoryService _repositoryService;

        public ImportService(IApiService apiService,
            IXmlService xmlService,
            IRepositoryService repositoryService)
        {
            _apiService = apiService;
            _xmlService = xmlService;
            _repositoryService = repositoryService;

            ConstructPipeline();
        }

        private BufferBlock<propertiesProperty> propertyBufferBlock;
        private TransformBlock<propertiesProperty, string> propertyXmlBlock;
        private TransformBlock<string, propertyType> propertyDeserializeBlock;
        private ActionBlock<propertyType> propertyCompleteBlock;

        public async Task<bool> ImportPropertiesForBranch(string branchName, int branchUrlId)
        {
            var propertyListXml = await _apiService.GetPropertyListAsync(branchUrlId);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyListXml))
                return false;

            var properties = _xmlService.DeserializePropertyList(propertyListXml);

            if (properties?.property == null || properties.property.Length == 0)
                return false;

            // limited to the first 20 for testing
            Parallel.For(0, 20,
                new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3},
                i => propertyBufferBlock.SendAsync(properties.property[i]));

            propertyBufferBlock.Complete();

            await propertyCompleteBlock.Completion;

            return true;
        }

        private void ConstructPipeline()
        {
            propertyBufferBlock = GetPropertyBuffer();
            propertyXmlBlock = GetPropertyXmlBlock();
            propertyDeserializeBlock = GetPropertyDeserializeBlock();
            propertyCompleteBlock = GetPropertyCompleteBlock();

            propertyBufferBlock.LinkTo(
                propertyXmlBlock,
                new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});

            propertyXmlBlock.LinkTo(
                propertyDeserializeBlock,
                new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});

            propertyDeserializeBlock.LinkTo(
                propertyCompleteBlock,
                new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
        }

        private BufferBlock<propertiesProperty> GetPropertyBuffer()
        {
            return new BufferBlock<propertiesProperty>();
        }

        private TransformBlock<propertiesProperty, string> GetPropertyXmlBlock()
        {
            return new TransformBlock<propertiesProperty, string>(async propertiesProperty =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"getting xml {propertiesProperty.prop_id}");
                    var propertyXml = await _apiService.GetXmlAsStringAsync(propertiesProperty.url);
                    return propertyXml;
                },
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
                    BoundedCapacity = 2
                });
        }

        private TransformBlock<string, propertyType> GetPropertyDeserializeBlock()
        {
            return new TransformBlock<string, propertyType>(xmlAsString =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"deserializing");
                    var propertyType = _xmlService.DeserializeProperty(xmlAsString);
                    return propertyType;
                },
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
                    BoundedCapacity = 2
                });
        }

        private ActionBlock<propertyType> GetPropertyCompleteBlock()
        {
            return new ActionBlock<propertyType>(propertyType =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"complete {propertyType.id}");
                    Debug.WriteLine(propertyType.address.display);
                },
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1,
                    BoundedCapacity = 2
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any potential bottlenecks or areas of the code that could be troublesome?

In general your approach looks good and the potential bottle neck is that you are limiting parallel processing of your blocks with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`. Based on the description of the problem each item can be processed independently of others and that's why you can process multiple items at a time.

> Is it ok to await async calls inside a `TransformBlock` or is this a bottleneck?

It is perfectly fine because TPL DataFlow supports async operations.

> Although the code works , I am worried about the buffering and asyncronsity of the `Parallel.For`, `BufferBlock` and async in the `TransformBlock`. I'm not sure its the best way and I maybe mixing up some concepts.

One, potential problem in your code that could make you shoot yourself in the foot is calling async method in `Parallel.For` and then calling `propertyBufferBlock.Complete();`. The problem here is that `Parallel.For` does not support async actions and the way you invoke it will call `propertyBufferBlock.SendAsync` and move on before returned task is completed. Which means that by the time `Parallel.For` exits some operations might still be in running state and items are not yet added to buffer block. And if you will then call `propertyBufferBlock.Complete();` those pending items will throw exception and items won't be added to processing. You will get unobserved exception.

You could use `ForEachAsync` form [this blog post](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2015/07/foreachasync.html) to ensure that all items are added to the block before completing the block. But if you are still limitting processing to 1 operation you can simply add items one at a time. I am not sure how `propertyBufferBlock.SendAsync` is implemented, but it can be that in will internally restrict to adding one item at a time so parallel adding would not make any sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's good to know I'm on the right track. After some experimentation I have removed the `Parallel.For` for the a simple `foreach` and now just `propertyBufferBlock.Post(property);`. I have also upped the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and the `BoundedCapacity` to great effect. I believe that my only limitation is now the 3rd Party Api Speed.

Comment: @madebybear, I would advice against using `bufferBlock.Post` because this is blocking method and will return only when the item is accepted for processing. I would rather suggest using `bufferBlock.SendAsync` and await it in a loop. It will release a thread and will increase overall throughput of the application.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have altered the code to a simple `foreach` with an `await bufferBlock.SendAsync (property)` inside the loop to the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You actually do some stuff in a wrong way:

```
i => propertyBufferBlock.SendAsync(properties.property[i])
```

You need to `await` method, otherwise you're creating too many simultaneous tasks.

Also this line:

```
MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
```

will limit the execution of your blocks to consequent execution, which can degrade your performance.

As you said in comments, you switched to **synchronous** method `Post` and have limited capacity of the blocks by setting the `BoundedCapacity`. This variant should be used with caution, as you need to check the return value of it, which stating, has the message had been accepted or not.

As for your worries of awaiting the `async` methods inside the blocks - it absolutely ok, and should be done as in other cases of `async` method usage.

Comment: Thank you for responding. @andrii-litvinov pointed this out and I have switched to a simple `foreach` with an `await sendAsync` inside the loop to the buffer.